# twitter bootstrap typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I am working on twitter bootstrap typeahead and i am stuck as i am not getting any error and yet the auto complete is not working.

this is my input field

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
```

and this is my script

```
<script>
    $('#autocomplete').typeahead({
            source: function(process) {
                var data =  <?php Widgets::allProducts() ?>;
                process(data);
        },

        matcher: function(item) {

            return
            item.name.toLocaleLowerCase()
                .indexOf(this.query.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1;

        },
        highlighter: function(item) {
            return item.name;

        },
        updater: function (item) {
            alert(JSON.parse(item).value);
            return JSON.parse(item).name;

        }
    });

</script>
```

this is how my `var data` looks like

```
var data =  [{"name":"Acne.org","id":"5"},{"name":"AcneFree","id":"6"},{"name":"Alpha Hydrox","id":"16"},{"name":"AmLactin","id":"17"},{"name":"Astara","id":"21"}];
```

What i want to do is get the product name listed (which is `name` in `var data` ) and upon selecting the product redirect the user to product page (with the help of product id which i am getting in `var data` as `id`).

I am just lost at this stage as i am not getting any error. I will appreciate any push to right direction.